# Многопоточность в win-службе на .net core

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, .net-core, service

Помогите разобраться с правильным использованием многопоточности в виндовс-службе, написанной на .net core. Есть служба, которая выполняет метод, в котором поочередно вызываются несколько других методов. Первый в этом же потоке (мой код), а остальные являются асинхронными и не редактируются(из Nuget-пакета). При запуске приложения как консольного - каждый их этих методов отрабатывает, нет никаких ошибок. Но если этот самый файл установить как вин-службу и запустить, то отрабатывает только первый из набора вызываемых методов. А остальные (асинхронные) пролетают мимо. Через них выполнение точно проходит, т.к. есть запись в лог после вызова каждого из них, записи с интервалом 2-3 мс. Есть ли разница в том, как работают потоки у консольного приложения и у вин-службы? Думал, что другие потоки не успевают отработать, ставил задержку на основном потоке. Не помогло.

Comment: `Есть ли разница в том, как работают потоки у консольного приложения и у вин-службы?` - Нет. Но есть разница например в том что возвращает `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` или учеткой под которой выполняется приложение.

Comment: Да, проблема была обнаружена в используемом пакете. Файл настроек служба искала в system32, т.к. его расположение указывалось как корень проекта, без Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() или т.п.. А логирование  в этот же файле и настраивается. Соответственно, всё проходило молча. без уведомлений.